# Connecting to an existing database in a ASP.NET MVC4 Web API project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm building an web api using ASP.NET web api framework. I have seen a few tutorials on how to get started but I haven't found to use an existing SQL Server database. I have the database up and running also added the data connection to the database explorer in VS but I don't know how to connect the database to my project so I can start using it as my repository. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Put the following in your application web.config file and replace "yourConnectionString" with the actual connection string.

```
<configuration>
       <connectionStrings>
           <add name="DbConnection" connectionString="yourConnectionString" />
       </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

In the code use `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbConnection"].ConnectionString` to get its value. You might need to reference the "System.Configuration" assembly in your project.